# Dependency injection and @Produces annotation for two classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

in this example, there are two injected classes, EntityManager and UserTransaction. I don't understand why UserTransaction can be directly injected without annotating it first, but the EntityManager has to be defined and annotated with a @Produces in a separate class?

Thanks in advance.

CarManager.java

```
public class CarManager {
@Inject
private EntityManager em;

@Inject
private UserTransaction utx;

private Long id;

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CarManager.class.getSimpleName());

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * Returns either a new instance or a managed instance of {@link Car}.
 * The produced entity should be dependent scoped to avoid incompatible proxies between
 * JPA and CDI.
 */
@Produces
public Car getCar() {
    if (id == null) {
        log.info("Returning new instance of Car");
        return new Car();
    }
    log.info("Finding instance of Car with id " + id);
    return em.find(Car.class, id);
}

...
}
```

EntityManagerProducer.java

```
public class EntityManagerProducer {
@Produces
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `UserTransaction` is so called Predefined bean, `EntityManager` is not thus it needs to have its own producer. See the [25.4 Using Predefined Beans in CDI Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv004.htm) for the list of predefined beans.

Comment: Hi, Petr, however, it says UserTransaction is a resource beans, not a CDI bean, and thus it used in this way: public class TransactionServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource UserTransaction transaction;
    ...
}

Comment: This might container-dependent, which one are you using?